# Main Launcher on Android

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, android-launcher, main-activity

I'm developing an android aplication that in the first time its used asks to configure the data and a keyword, after completing this form is directed to a homepage. In the second use, and in the following the main launcher happens to be a login, where you have to put the keyword that you configured previously and only after that you have access to the application's menu. My difficulty is in the first use, I use a main launcher and in the following I need to use a different main launcher.

Comment: you can only have 1 launcher. Make a splash activity or something that you use as entry point and determine in that whether to show screen A or B

Comment: I'm not familar with the splash activity, can you explain it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the app was started the first time using `SharedPreferences` in your `onCreate` and if so, start your configuration activity:

```
val prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val startedFirstTime = prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", true) // Returns true, if nothing was saved before
if(startedFirstTime) {
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstTime", false).apply()
    // TODO Start your configuration activity
}
```

SharedPreferences are used to store simple data.

Comment: And I put this code on the activity that I want to launche the first time our in the activity I want to launche in the second time?

Comment: In your main activity that should always launch after configuration. Do you need the Java code or is Kotlin ok?

Comment: Ah, then I put it in the right place. Kotlin is ok.